# subquery returns more tha one row

Tags: mysql, subquery

I want to update data of a table where data-name matches with another table and also one data are common with many items.
For example, I have a cycle in which tyre is a part and quantity of tyre is 500. Now I had a new brand cycle in which tyre is also required. When i issue one cycle then i want to update tyre quantity and if i issue another cycle then i also want to update the same tyre quantity. I applied this quarry of MySQL

update available set quantity = quantity - '"+v1+"' * ( select required from byproduct where subitem = (select subitem where name = '"+v2+"'))

i was trying to this i got an error like " subquery returns more than one row". After that, I searched on the internet and applied IN at the place of "subitem=" i got a new error "integer constraint violation exception" . Please help me to solve this

Comment: post a fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/ which demonstrates the error, and update the post with that url

Comment: Look into multi-table `UPDATE`.